# Issues with Apache redirect to www-prefixed URL

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have a website with domain mysite.com. I would like to have it so that if a user types in "mysite.com" it will redirect to "www.mysite.com". Additionally, "mysite.com/subdir" will also redirect to "www.mysite.com/subdir". I've looked and made changes with vhosts and also rewrites, but it's not working for the "mysite.com/subdir"->"www.mysite.com/subdir" case. 
Every time I type in "mysite.com/subdir", it will redirect to "www.mysite.com". Only "www.mysite.com/subdir" works.

Not sure how to troubleshoot this. I turned on rewrite logs and didn't see anything obvious, yet.

This is my config files so far. Please let me know what I'm missing. Thanks!

FYI: I'm using CentOS 5.4, nginx 1.2.0 on top of Apache 2.2.3. The site itself is built with CodeIgniter framework.

http.conf:

```
ServerTokens Prod

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

PidFile run/httpd.pid

Timeout 120

KeepAlive Off

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 15

<IfModule prefork.c>

StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   10
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       60
MaxRequestsPerChild  10000

#StartServers       8
#MinSpareServers    5
#MaxSpareServers   20
#ServerLimit      256
#MaxClients       256
#MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         2
MaxClients         150
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

Listen 69

LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so

#rpaf settings
LoadModule rpaf_module modules/mod_rpaf-2.0.so
RPAFenable On
RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1
RPAFsethostname On
# The header where the real client IP address is stored.
RPAFheader X-Forwarded-For


Include conf.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

ServerName www.mysite.com:80

UseCanonicalName Off

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_userdir.c>

    UserDir disable

</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<DirectoryMatch "^/.*/\.svn/">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>

TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog logs/error_log
LogLevel warn
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

CustomLog logs/access_log combined

ServerSignature Off

Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>


ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable

AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip

AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*

AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core

AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^

DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif

#AddDescription "GZIP compressed document" .gz
#AddDescription "tar archive" .tar
#AddDescription "GZIP compressed tar archive" .tgz

ReadmeName README.html
HeaderName HEADER.html

IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t

AddLanguage ca .ca
AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
AddLanguage da .dk
AddLanguage de .de
AddLanguage el .el
AddLanguage en .en
AddLanguage eo .eo
AddLanguage es .es
AddLanguage et .et
AddLanguage fr .fr
AddLanguage he .he
AddLanguage hr .hr
AddLanguage it .it
AddLanguage ja .ja
AddLanguage ko .ko
AddLanguage ltz .ltz
AddLanguage nl .nl
AddLanguage nn .nn
AddLanguage no .no
AddLanguage pl .po
AddLanguage pt .pt
AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br
AddLanguage ru .ru
AddLanguage sv .sv
AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw

LanguagePriority en zh-CN zh-TW ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv

ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

AddType text/x-component .htc

AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

AddHandler type-map var

AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml


Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0

BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully
```

vhost.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:69

<VirtualHost *:69>
  ServerName mysite.com
  ServerAlias vip.mysite.com
  Redirect / http://www.mysite.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:69>
  DocumentRoot /home/mysite/mysite/www
  ServerName www.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:69>
  DocumentRoot /home/mysite/mysite/www/assets
  ServerName static.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:69>
  DocumentRoot /home/mysite/admin/www
  ServerName admin.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:69>
  DocumentRoot /home/other/trunk/www
  ServerName othersite.com
  ServerAlias www.othersite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:69>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName test.mysite.com
  ServerAlias test2.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

/home/mysite/mysite/www/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# In my case all CI files are outside this web root, so we can
# allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# hide index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]


# BEGIN Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Compress text files


# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers


# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, private"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers


# BEGIN Turn ETags Off
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None
# END Turn ETags Off
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name static.mysite.com;
    location / {
        root   /home/mysite/mysite/www/assets;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    expires max;
    }

}



server {
    listen       80;
    server_name *.mysite.com www.mysite.com vip.mysite.com;

    #Set this larger if uploading big files
    client_max_body_size 5m;

    location /
    {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:69;
        proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_send_timeout 90;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;

    #client_max_body_size 10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    proxy_buffer_size 4k;
    proxy_buffers 4 32k;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have nginx do the redirection instead of passing them up to Apache.

Example:

```
server {
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name example.com vip.example.com;
   return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

(Taken from my site [www.yes-www.org](http://www.yes-www.org/redirection/))

Comment: But because I'm using CodeIgniter. I would like to hide the index.php at the end.

Comment: What does that have to do with this?

Comment: What I meant was, the htaccess file doesn't need to be edited right? Because htaccess is doing the hiding. What adjustments are needed for the vhost.conf for apache?

Answer (score 0):

Your apache RewriteRule will not work; also, do not use .htaccess files if you can avoid doing so.

The Redirect inside the mysite vhost is sufficient to have all requests end up at www.mysite.com.

However, the subsequent RewriteRule would rewrite everything to /index.php/$0 (literally), since $0 doesn't mean anything.

Why is nginx proxying everything to an apache backend ? What, exactly, does nginx add here ?

You should collect logs from apache (inspect both the access and the error logs) to determine what is happening.

Comment: notice the static.mysite.com is directly being served by nginx. but the dynamic pages done with php is proxied over to apache. Additionally, I'm using CodeIgniter. And the htaccess file helps with the hiding of the index.php. And yes, the structure of CodeIgniter needs everything to be pass through index.php.

Comment: There is no reason to use .htaccess files if you have access to httpd.conf. Please consider adding that configuration to your httpd.conf/vhost file(s).

Comment: Would moving the htaccess code over to vhost config make any difference though in terms of what I'm currently experiencing? (Not just on a performance level)

Comment: I have no idea what you're currently experiencing, since, as I said, you need to start collecting log data. Running a webserver is not a trivial excercise.